# How to format javascript Date.toString() to dd/mm/yy hh:mm

Tags: javascript, html, css, date, reactjs

Does Javascript Date API provide any method to format the string output of Date object to a form of `dd/mm/yy hh:mm`? I don't want to include any external library for this task, so is my only choice to write a custom function to perform the task?

Comment: Did you go through https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff743760(v=vs.94).aspx

Comment: Here's another great resource https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: What have you tried so far? You can also check - http://www.w3schools.com/Js/js_date_formats.asp